# Why did Haman have to parade Mordechai around?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther

After Haman describes what a king should do to someone he wants to honor, he immediately orders Haman do it to Mordechai. Why davka Haman? Why would the king want to dishonor one of his greatest ministers in such a way?

Also, why would the king allow his crown to be worn by someone else (or even the horse according to [some translations](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.6.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))? Wouldn't that debase the meaning of the symbol of his power?

Comment: Why would it be a dishonor to Haman? It was his idea and it would show great honor to Mordechai that a grand vizier (one of the שָּׂרֵ֤י הַמֶּ֙לֶךְ֙ הַֽפַּרְתְּמִ֔ים
) proclaims that Mordechai did something good for the king. As for the issue of the crown, the Ibn Ezra seems to say that this was just part of the description of which horse -- one upon which the king has ridden, so it gets a crown (יש סוס של מלך שישימו כתר מלכות בראשו כאשר ירכב עליו המלך
), but that when Mordechai rode it, there was no crown.

Comment: I think this could support the opinion that the king was suspicious of Haman and was even nervous that when Haman came to him that night, he was planning on killing him (midrash in Pirkei D’Rabbi Eliezer says this). And he was suspicious also because Esther invited himself and Haman to some strange mishteh so perhaps the king thought there was some funny business going on between the two of them. So when Haman suggested the reward to be a grand parade, the king knew he was hoping it would be him and then davka did the opposite as a way to humble Haman

Comment: @rosends Some read it as the horse he rode during his coronation. But I remember hearing that Haman wanted the crown but Achashverosh didn't agree to that, as hinted by his response only referencing the garb and the horse.

Comment: @shmosel the Ibn Ezra on 6:8 seems to refer to something like that יש אומרים שהרגיש שחרה על המלך על כתר המלכות בעבור כבוד המלכות על כן אמר ונתון הלבוש והסוס ולא הזכיר הכתר